# How to deallocate /dev/ram0

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, kernel-modules, ramdisk

I have allocated `/dev/ram0`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ram0 bs=1M count=1024
```

Now I have 1Gb sitting in memory. How do I free up the allocated space?

Comment: I don't have a ramdisk to test, but how about `truncate /dev/ram0`?

Comment: How is [this Q+A](http://superuser.com/questions/319479/how-do-i-deallocate-a-linux-ramdisk-e-g-dev-ram0) not serving you?

Comment: I wonder whether the method describes is the correct way to allocate a ramdisk: First the file created will be a normal file, not a block device, and second if `/dev` is not a ramdisk itself, you will not create a ramdisk hat way. Anyway: If you created it that way a simple `rm` should deallocate the space being used (assuming all references closed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you can use `blockdev` command, which is available from `util-linux` package (in Debian)

```
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0
```

[Source](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=61488#10)

Comment: This is spot-on for `brd` ramdisks. It beats my `rmmod` + `modprobe` solution easily

Comment: I doubt thiis is the answer: Doesn't it free the cache *related* to `/dev/ram0`? The manual page is rather vague on that. Probably the ramdisk driver does something special *instead* of flushing the buffers.

Comment: Are you sure it should work? I am not able to reproduce that here `modprobe brd rd_nr=3 && ls /dev/ram*` lists `ram0` and others. Then, `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0 && ls /dev/ram*` — but the device is still sitting there.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `brd` for the ramdisk**

Using `brd` for the ramdisk, the only way to free up the RAM is by removing the module from the kernel, or by a reboot. `freeramdisk` does not work (for me).

Here is an example of usage

```
apt-get install loadln                # Contains "freeramdisk" command
modprobe brd rd_size=$((1024*128))    # 128MB
free -m                               # total=1000 used=356 free=643
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M of=/dev/ram0    # writes 128 x 1MB records (as expected)
free -m                               # total=1000 used=485 free=515
freeramdisk                           # "freeramdisk: cannot open /dev/ram: No such file or directory"
free -m                               # total=1000 used=485 free=515
rmmod brd                             # REMOVE ALL THE RAM DISKS
free -m                               # total=1000 used=358 free=641
```

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to determine the original size of the ramdisk other than by using `dd` to read the device until failure. However, given these devices are implicitly small it wouldn't take long to do this. Thus a "quick reset" command can be created:

```
resetramdisk() {
    mb=$(dd if=/dev/ram0 bs=1M of=/dev/null 2>&1 | sed -n 's/+.*//p;q')
    if test -n "$mb"
    then
        rmmod brd
        modprobe brd rd_size=$((1024*$mb))
    fi
}
```

**Using kernel boot-time ramdisk**

I believe that these disks can be freed up with `freeramdisk`, but I don't have a configuration that I can test right now.

Comment: Adding as a comment rather than as an edit to say that `blockdev --flushbufs /dev/ram0` works far better than my initially proposed `rmmod` + `modprobe`. Kudos to @[Martin Vegter](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43007/martin-vegter) who has offered another answer here

Comment: Another good question would be why a ramdisk *isn't* `removable` (as per `/sys/block/ram0/removable` being `0`).

Comment: @U.Windl it is a good question. Care to ask it (and get a +1 from me)?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/616646/320598